# convert opencv cv::Vec3b to eigen Matrix <unsigned char, 3, 1>

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I have the following:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix <unsigned char, 3, 1> Vec3b_eigen;
```

Then I read the rgb(actually bgr) value at a specific pixel with:

```
cv::Vec3b bgr_cv = image.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
```

Then I want to convert `bgr_cv` into a variable of type `Vec3b_eigen`.

I done the following but it didn't worked:

```
Vec3b_eigen rgb_eigen = {bgr_cv(2), bgr_cv(1), bgr_cv(1)};
```

I also used `cv2eigen()` like this,

```
cv::Vec3b bgr_cv = image.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
Vec3b_eigen rgb_eigen;
cv::cv2eigen(bgr_cv,rgb_eigen);
```

But it didn't work too..

Comment: it is bgr_cv[index 0 .. 2] ... you've tried the wrong kind of brackets.

Comment: oh sorry, i've typed it wrong here, but in my code I actually have the correct brackets 
Vec3b_eigen rgb_eigen = {bgr_cv[2], bgr_cv[1], bgr_cv[1]};
it seen to work, the code compile and run but when I print the value of **rgb_eigen** using 
**std::cout<< rgb_eigen << std:.endl;** 
it give me strange character..

Comment: `unsigned char` are characters. typecast them to `int` or sth. during printing, to dispay them as numbers.

Comment: Do you intentionally take index 1 of `bgr_cv` twice? And to add to the comment by @Micka : Casting an Eigen type can be done like this: `std::cout << rgb_eigen.cast<int>() << '\n';`

Comment: Thanks a lot you two guys.. I was struggling on it for hours.. Now it work like a charm :) 
PS: @chtz  I was accidentally taking bgr_cv[1] twice. Thanks for the remark..